# Error: Notice: undefined index and creates null data when first opens page

Tags: php, mysqli, null, indexing, undefined

The follweing code IS working (it sends the data to the database). But I'm getting the "Notice: undefined index" as soon as I open the page and also it creates a null line (I mean, onde null value for each field) in the database. If I fill in the fields and submit it will work and they will be saved in the database alright, though. I think I need a code that will tell "submit" not to send data to the database it empty. What code is that? i'm not familiar with mysqli.

```
<?php
$con=mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","activitytest1");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
  {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
  }

$sql="INSERT INTO activitytest1 (type, description, author, outcome, pre, whileact, postact, path, books, grouping, time)
VALUES
('$_POST[type]','$_POST[description]','$_POST[author]','$_POST[outcome]','$_POST[pre]','$_POST[whileact]','$_POST[postact]','$_POST[path]','$_POST[books]','$_POST[grouping]','$_POST[time]')";

if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
  }
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM activitytest1");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo "<br/>

<table width='909' border='1' align='center' cellpadding='5' cellspacing='0'>
  <tr>
    <td width='125'>" . $row['type'] .  "</th>
    <td width='680'>" . $row['description'] .  "</th>
    <td width='120'>" . $row['author'] .  "</th>
  </tr></table> <br/>" . $row['pre'] .  "<br/>" . $row['whileact'] .  "<br/>" . $row['postact'] .  "<br/>" . $row['outcome'] .  "<br/>" . $row['path'] . "<br/>" . $row['books'] .  "<br/>" . $row['grouping'] .  "<br/>" . $row['time'] . "<hr size='1'/>";
  }

mysqli_close($con);
?>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test 1</title>
</head>
<body>

<br>
<table width="909" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <th width="125" scope="col">Type</th>
    <th width="680" scope="col">Description</th>
    <th width="120" scope="col">Author</th>
  </tr></table>
  <br>
<form action="index.php" method="POST">

<table width="909" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="0">
     <td width="125"><label>

     </label>
       <select name="type" id="type" onChange="display(this,'Task','Semi-task','Practice','Exercise','Lead-in');">
         <option value="Unselected" selected="selected">Choose one:</option>
         <option value="Task">Task</option>
         <option value="Semi-task">Semi-task</option>
         <option value="Practice">Practice</option>
         <option value="Exercise">Exercise</option>
         <option value="Lead-in">Lead-in</option>
         <option value="Game">Game</option>
         <option value="Video">Video</option>
         <option value="Song">Song</option>
         <option value="Mimio">Mimio</option>
         <option value="Other">Other</option>
       </select></td>
    <td width="680"><div id="Semi-task" style="display: none;">
      Pre:<br>
    </div>
        <div id="Exercise"  style="display: none;">whileact:</div>
        <br>
        <div id="Practice" style="display: none;">
      Post:<br>
      <br>
       </div>
        <div id="Task"  style="display: none;"> Outcome: <br />
        <textarea name="description" cols="70" rows="2"></textarea>
            <br />
        </div>
        <div id="Lead-in" style="display: none;">
      Link/Path:<br>
      <br>
       </div></td>
    <td width="120"><input name="author" type="text" size="12" maxlength="25" /></td>
  </tr>
     <tr>
       <td colspan="3">      <textarea name="pre" id="Pre" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
                       <br /><textarea name="whileact" id="whileact" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
                       <br /><textarea name="postact" id="Post" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
                       <br /><textarea name="outcome" id="Outcome" cols="45" rows="5"></textarea>
                       <br /><input type="text" name="path" id="Path" />
                       <br /><input type="text" name="books" id="Books" />
                       <br /><input type="text" name="grouping" id="Grouping" />
                       <br /><input type="text" name="time" id="Time" />
                       </td>
     </tr>
    <tr>
       <td colspan="3"><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Comment" /></td>
     </tr>
</table>
</form>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The full error is: Notice: Undefined index: type in C:\wamp\www\activities_data\index.php on line 59 (there are actually 11 errors, all the same thing, one for each of the 11 variables/fields)

Comment: If `type` is not defined from the form, it will throw that notice. Wrap the statement in `if (isset($_POST['type']) { ..... }; and it should stop that error. This goes the same for any other variable throwing that notice.

Comment: You should also check and see if a POST is even being made with `if(isset($_POST['whatever'])` that might be another reason

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP code is running every time the page loads. When you load it for the first time, none of the `$_POST` variables are set; so you're seeing the undefined index errors, and it's adding a blank row to the database.

You need a check in your PHP to see if the page has been submitted -you just need to wrap the PHP code in an if statement

```
if (isset($_POST['submit])) {
.......
```

You can additionally use the same function for each of the values you're inserting, so you can validate the data before you insert to the database:

```
 if (! isset($_POST['type'])) {
      $errorMessage = "Please a Type";
 } elseif (! isset($_POST['description'])) {
      ......
```

You might also want to look at binding those variables and using a prepared statement; otherwise, you're exposing your code to an SQL injection vulnerability. You're already using `mysqli_`, so you might as well take advantage and let it help you write more secure code.

Comment: Thank you, andrewsi! Wrapping the insert function with that submit code that  you posted did the trick. But now I can't type anything  that has a an apostrophe (or single quotation mark) in the fields (like "let's" or "he's" or "student's", cause it interferes in the code and results in a mysql error. Can you help me a little more and point me another piece of code that will prevent apostrophes typed into the form fields to interfere in the code? Thank you very much for your feedback.

Comment: @jcodi - have a look at http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php - you can bind the values, instead of adding them directly into the string. Example 2 on that page should show you what you need to do.

Answer (score 0):

You could add javascript code to stop the form submitting if fields are empty, however that doesn't stop someone bypassing those checks and still sending bad data to your script. Also if they don't have javascript running then the checks won't happen.

In both cases you need to alter the PHP code to only store data into the database once it has been verified for null and all SQL injection attacks have been protected from.

Basically only perform the SQL insert after you have checked that all fields have input and make sure all input is passed through htmlentities() before being inserted into your database.

If there are errors in the input I would also reload the form with the original values defaulted and a nice message explaining which fields need to be completed before the form will be accepted.